# cut a part from an mp4 video with no wreckage using ffmpeg and php

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I use this cmd below to cut a part from an MP4 video:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10.500 -i {$ffmpeg_mp4_vinput} -t 00:00:17.430 {$ffmpeg_mp4_voutput} 2>&1
```

and

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10.500 -i {$ffmpeg_mp4_vinput} -to 00:00:17.430 {$ffmpeg_mp4_voutput} 2>&1
```

and

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10.500 -i {$ffmpeg_mp4_vinput} -t 7 {$ffmpeg_mp4_voutput} 2>&1
```

All those cmds are called by `exec()` php function, they all work fine with `SAME` result.

Problem is when I cut a video with one of those commands, I get a video with long video from what I set in from-to in the commands. For example I get 1 second before and more than 2+ seconds after.

Is there something missed out from the commands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract time-accurate video segments with ffmpeg?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420296/how-to-extract-time-accurate-video-segments-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: @GrishaLevit, yep, same question.. thank you!