# Export .osp OpenShot project to ffmpeg script as workaround to video export freeze or crash by swap hell

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, cut

I have a big video rush 35".

With OpenShot i've cut more than 30 small sequences and concatenate them into one 25" sequence.

Now i try to export the result as video file but OneShot randomly crash or freeze during the export/encoding between 40% and 80% so after more than an hour of encoding. It look to be a memory leek and a swap saturation with memory allocation deny because no space left.

I've tried with x264(mp4) and vp8(webm) encoding, but nothing worked.

I've opened the .osp file, it's a big json file with all the clips referred like this :

```
{
  clips:[
    {
      title: "<clipFileName.ext>",
      start:<seconds>.<decimals>,
      end:<seconds>.<decimals>,
      position:<seconds>.<decimals>
    }
  ]
}
```

- `title` if not renamed is the inputFileName.
- `start` clip start time from the input file beginning
- `end` clip end time from the input file beginning
- `position` clip start position in the output file timeline

I've read [ffmpeg can extract video parts / subclip / sequences with cut function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420296/how-to-extract-time-accurate-video-segments-with-ffmpeg) :

`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:09.000 -i input.mp4 -to 00:00:20 output.mp4`

Time can be `hh:mm:ss.xxx` or `hh:mm:ss` or any amount of `seconds`, allowing decimals.

I've also read [ffmpeg can concat sequences](https://superuser.com/questions/1059245/ffmpeg-join-two-mp4-files-with-ffmpeg-on-command-line) : 

`ffmpeg -i "concat:input1.ts|input2.ts|input3.ts" output.ts`

So, how to encode my video with these project data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i build the following script to extract all clips as video files and then concat them :

```js
function parser(e){
  const commandList = [];
  const outputFilesName = []
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(){
    const j = JSON.parse(reader.result);
    j.clips.forEach(function(c){
      const fileName = f3d(c.position) + '.ts';
      outputFilesName.push(fileName);
      let cmd = `ffmpeg -i ${c.title} -ss ${f3d(c.start)} -to ${f3d(c.end)} `;
      cmd+= `-c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -f mpegts `;
      cmd+= fileName;
      commandList.push(cmd);
    });
    const script = `Go to your video rush folder and run the following script :
    
${commandList.join(' && ')} && ffmpeg -i "concat:${outputFilesName.join('|')}" -c copy concatenated.mp4`
    document.getElementById('commands').innerHTML = script;
  };
  reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
}

document.getElementById('osp').addEventListener('change', parser, false);
function f3d(floatNumber){
  return Math.round(floatNumber*1000)/1000;
}
```

```html
<input id="osp" type="file" accept=".osp"/>

<pre id="commands"></pre>
```